# Accessing temporary value of a Nest evaluation

Tags: memory, system-variables, undocumented

The function `Nest[]` must store the temporary values in the memory somewhere (those values that would form the entries of the list which is returned by the equivalent `NestList` function).

Does anyone know if there is a way to access said values in an interrupted evaluation (using a kernel subsession)?

Alternatively, is there a way to know all temporary variables currently in use and to print out their values?

Comment: So you want to manualy abort `Nest` when you see that current value is what you want?

Comment: Probably some sort of `Reap` and `Sow` combination but some more details would be welcome.

Comment: You can assign a value to an arbitrary control variable in the function you are `Nest`ing and display that any way you like... In any case, some code/MWE would be very helpful.

Comment: Let's say I started an iterative computation, e.g. an optimization and it takes too long. Instead of waiting until it's finished (if it ever does), I want to check where it currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to run a `Nest` command. In cases where the `Nest` takes a long time you'd like to abort (or suspend) the command and then through an interactive debugging session see the values obtained thus far. If this is what you are asking, to the best of my knowledge this is not possible. You need to add code (like `Sow`) prior to the execution.

Comment: Does `Reap` also work for interrupted evaluations?

Comment: @YvesKlett, I have never tried that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do! Thanks!

Comment: @YvesKlett, not natively, as I can see. But `CheckAbort` may be used. Like:
`Reap[CheckAbort[Do[Pause[0.1]; Sow[x], {x, 100}]; $Success, $Aborted]]`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about temporary values, but if you want to monitor the progression of `Nest` you could use the following:

```
intensiveCalculation[x_] := (Pause[0.5]; x + 1)

Nest[(PrintTemporary[#]; #) &@ intensiveCalculation[#] &, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `Dynamic` to give you a constantly updated progress indicator:

```
intensiveCalculation[x_] := (Pause[0.5]; x + 1)

Dynamic[y]

Nest[(y = #; intensiveCalculation[#]) &, 1, 10]
```